# Custom price per month on product page in Woocommerce

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce, hook

Hello dear Stackoverflow. Long time reader, first time writer.

We are running a webstore (with Woocommerce on Wordpress) with high-end prices and of course then we have installment plans. I like to show this on the product page itself (namely before "add to cart form"). And I made this simple custom code which should calculate month-to-month price, however what I receive on the page is a stop in the code before "add to cart form" so there is an error here, but I cannot see it.

Is there anybody out there who can help me or point me in a direction? Really appreciate it!

By the way, no interest rate when the installment plan is 12 months or less. That's why I did not include interest rate.

(Code has been edited to reflect solution to the problem)

```
// Price per month

add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form', 'price_per_month', 5 );

function price_per_month() {

    global $product
    $price = $product->get_price();
    $price = $price + 295;
    $months = 12;
    $fee = 39;
    //$register_fee = 295;

    $price_per_month = ($price / $months);
    $total_per_month = $price_per_month + $fee;

    echo "
    <div id='ppm-container'>
        <div id='ppm-text'>
            Pay from only ". $total_per_month ." NOK per month.
        </div>
    </div>
    ";
}
```

Comment: first on the debug mode in wp-config.php file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few things

First you need to have

```
global $product
```

Second,
Use WP_DEBUG in order to see errors

Comment: Awesome! Thanks! It worked with just adding global $product at the start of the function! Kudos

Comment: great. you are more than welcome to accept the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Why are you writing add_action before defining the function price_per_month?

Comment: As far as I know, it shouldn't matter before or after. It is now tested working with just adding "global $product" at the start of the code per answer from Shir Gans.